# Which posts need screenshots?

Tags: discussion

Which posts on AskUbuntu need a screenshot? We can make a list here (and remove a post when screenshot is added) so it is easier to search for posts that need screenshots and add them.

Answer (score 7):

Good idea! I recommend perhaps starting with those questions which have a lot of views:

https://askubuntu.com/search?q=views%3A7500

More advanced search options are at https://askubuntu.com/search

[image: Screenshot]